# Image in UIScrollView changes position after scrolling the table

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, gpuimage

I have a UITableView Cell that contains a UIScroller that has a UIImage in it.

I am having an issue where by when I first load the view, everything looks OK, but when I scroll up and down it changes.

Here is a screen shot of before:

[image]

And here is one after I do a scroll:

[image]

My code that loads the UIImage in the UIScroller is:

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

        imageview.frame = self.scrollview.bounds;

        self.scrollview.delegate = self;

        [self.scrollview addSubview:imageview];
```

Can someone give me some pointers? I tried using code from the following stack overflow posts but they have not been able to do the trick so far:

[UIImage Is Not Fitting In UIScrollView At Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161786/uiimage-is-not-fitting-in-uiscrollview-at-start)
[UIScrollView with centered UIImageView, like Photos app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638299/uiscrollview-with-centered-uiimageview-like-photos-app)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `contentSize` of your scrollview to the dimensions of your imageview might help.

Comment: did that but it didnt do anything. Same thing happens when I scroll the UITableView